# A List of Lists containing int and string, need to output X strings with highest int values based on TrackBar (not a sorted list)

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting

I have a List structured as:

```
"Then a sentence woop", 340 
"and another one",      256
"in order they appear", 700
"in a linked file",     304
```

The list contains the highest scored sentence from each paragraph of a text file. I need to output each sentence, but with a track bar reduce how many are shown.

So remove the sentence with the lowest score, the issue is the list is ordered by the sentences appearance in the original text, and the output needs to be in this order. So if I had a track bar for the above list, it would have 4 points. If I move it to point 3 sentence 2 would vanish, point 2 sentence 2 and 4 would vanish.

The code where the list is generated is:

```
    public List<ScoredSentence> buildSummarySentenceList()
    {
        List<ScoredSentence> ultimateScoreslist = new List<ScoredSentence>();
        scoreCoord2 = -1;
        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < results.Length; x1++)
        {
            List<ScoredSentence> paragraphsScorelist = new List<ScoredSentence>();
            for (int x2 = 0; x2 < results[x1].Length; x2++)
            {
                scoreCoord2++;
                paragraphsScorelist.Add(new ScoredSentence(results[x1][x2], intersectionSentenceScores[scoreCoord2]));
            }
            var maxValue = paragraphsScorelist.Max(s => s.score);

            string topSentence = paragraphsScorelist.First(s => s.score == maxValue).sentence;
            int topScore = paragraphsScorelist.First(s => s.score == maxValue).score;

            ultimateScoreslist.Add(new ScoredSentence(topSentence, topScore));
        }
        return ultimateScoreslist;
    }

    public class ScoredSentence
    {
        public string sentence { get; set; }
        public int score { get; set; }

        public ScoredSentence(string sentence, int score)
        {
            this.sentence = sentence;
            this.score = score;
        }
    }
```

This code loops though a jagged array and a list of sentence to sentence scores, it results in a list as shown at the top.

Currently I output every sentence, and set the trackbar to be as long as there are sentences:

```
    protected void summaryOutput()
    {
        List<ScoredSentence> ultimateScoreslist = buildSummarySentenceList();
        trackBSummaryPercent.Maximum = ultimateScoreslist.Count;
        lblNoOfLines.Text += trackBSummaryPercent.Maximum.ToString();
        //make 2 lists for the reduction????
        for (var x = 0; x < ultimateScoreslist.Count; x++)
        {
            TextboxSummary.Text += ultimateScoreslist[x].sentence + "\n";
        }
    }
```

I have thought of on every onchange tick of the trackbar to have a second clone list and remove the lowest value entry. Then when the bar is moved up to somehow move the missing entries back from the clone list. I don't like this method as it may cause program speed issues when for example my current test text is 100 paragraphs long, and moving the trackbar a lot may make it become slow.

Comment: this question fits better at programmers.SE

Comment: @DrKoch What makes you think that?

Comment: @Simon Well, I can't see a specific problem here, rather a more general design question.

Comment: This feels like an implementation question to me.  The design has already been chosen.

Comment: While I answered it, I'm still fuzzy on the difference between the two. I've read all the information and still have trouble deciding.  I can see @DrKoch's point because the OP has a working implementation that needs to be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a displayed property to your `ScoredSentence` object.  Then whenever the list changes, or the track bar selection changes, run this method on it to update the set of displayed elements.  The main list should always be sorted in the order you want it displayed. `numberToDisplay` would be calculated by whatever means you are using to go from your UI to the number of items.

```
public void OnUpdate()
{
   var orderedEnumerable = ScoresList.OrderByDescending (s => s.Score);

   foreach (var s in orderedEnumerable.Take (numberToDisplay)) 
   {
      s.Displayed = true;
   }
   foreach (var s in orderedEnumerable.Skip(numberToDisplay)) 
   {
      s.Displayed = false;
   }
}
```

Then use the following instead of the list whenever you need to display it

```
ScoredSentences.Where(s=> s.Displayed);
```